# How not to stretch a uniform grid between two auto-sized rows in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

At the moment, I have a grid with three rows and three columns.
Row 0 is auto-sized, as well as row 2.
In Row 1 have a uniformgrid, but the problem is that I don't have as many items in the uniformgrid to stretch the whole window resolution, so the items in the uniformgrid tend to have top and bottom-margin so they can stretch the whole window. I want to dynamically add items, so the uniformgrid has to place my Items the right way for the differrent amount of buttons in my uniformgrid. I now have something like this:

[image: Grid with the outer rows auto-sized and uniform grid in the middle row]

What I want is when I have 5 buttons, the buttons are close to each other, as well as when I have 10 buttons. When I reach the end of the window-size with my uniformgrid, I want to have a scrollviewer so that I can scroll through the grid.

Some xaml code:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text = "Bestelling van tafel" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="75">

        </TextBlock>

        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20" Height="auto">
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
            <Button Height="200" Width="200"></Button>
        </UniformGrid>

        <Image Margin="20" Style="{StaticResource smallButtonStyle }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="resources/images/close.png" Height="75" Width="75" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have u tried setting the alignment for the uniformgrid? while for the scroller then u can wrap the unformgrid with scrollvoiewer or create an itemscontrol with uniformgrid as its panel

Comment: Wow, i feel like a real noob... The vertical alignment setting did the right thing. Now I begin to wonder if a uniformgrid is the right sort of lay-out for my goal.